# Как можно перенести запрос в настройки?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

```
public interface QuestionRepository extends CrudRepository<Question, Long> {
    List<Question> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String search);

    // Как бы ее перенести в настройки?
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM QUESTION",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Question> findQuestions();
```

Так как она используется в иплементации

```
@Override
public List<QuestionsItemDTO> getQuestionToSession() {
    List<QuestionsItemDTO> questionsItemDTOList =
        questionRepository.findQuestions()
            .stream()
            .map(question -> {
                List<Answer> answers = answerRepository.findByQuestion(question);
                return new QuestionsItemDTO(question,answers);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return questionsItemDTOList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашел можно ипсользовать FindAll()